# Project File Line Suppression State Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'python310_d.lib'

Tags: python, c++

I wrote a program for learning how to embed python in c++ . But when I try to run it in visual studio It shows a linker error that **python310_d.lib** is not found. I searched for this file in my python directory lib folder but there was no such file with this name. So now I need a way to somehow get that file. Please help me.

## Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("print(\'Hellow Python\')");

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

## Here are my errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'python310_d.lib'  Project1    C:\Users\noob\source\repos\Project1\Project1\LINK   1
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of my screen]

Comment: ***I searched for this file in my python directory lib folder but there was no such file with this name. So now I need a way to somehow get that file*** You probably only have the release libraries.

Comment: This may help you get the debug libraries: [https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3403#issuecomment-951485263](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3403#issuecomment-951485263)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the problem is you don't have the debug libraries installed. By default the installer will not install these unless you check the option to download these:
[image]

The picture and information for this answer was found in the following link:
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3403#issuecomment-951485263

Comment: I did check that and the error still persists. Why?